# Is it mathematically proper to denote multiples terms in superscript?

Tags: notation

Let's say I have function $f$, but it's from set $k$, at level $l$  in terms of $a, b, c$ like this:

$f^{k, l}_{a, b, c} = ...$

Is it mathematically correct? I've never seen superscript that denote two terms so far, only subscript.

Comment: Its acceptable, but I would choose $f_{a,b,c}^{(k,l)}$ just in case you have exponents.

Comment: Since you define your notation, there is no problem with this. They are only symbols. But you have to introduce it properly!

Comment: Thank you guys, that helps. I keep doubting the way I notate it since I've never seen such usage.

Comment: @Wuestenfux How do I notates it if I have an exponent? Is something like $(f^{k, l}_{a, b, c})^2$ correct? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Two examples of multiple superscripts: [Sobolev spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#One-dimensional_case) $W^{k,p}$, [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) $g^{\mu\nu}$

Comment: I would recommend using parentheses like you do: $(f^{k, l}_{a, b, c})^2$. That will make it clear that ${}^2$ is not a superscript index.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is well-defined, it is acceptable as long as you have some way to disambiguate this from exponents (e.g. promising that you won't use exponents when you use this notation).

Indeed, this notation is actually used in practice, e.g. when denoting a covariant index of a tensor: $T^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\nu}$.